# moment.js with locale not working in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am validating a date in moment.js in format `D. MMM YYYY` and then converting it to format `YYYY-MM-DD`. While validating it keeps on giving me invalid date. Below is the code.

```
var date = '26. Mär 1995';
var mom = moment(date, "D. MMM YYYY","de", true);

 if (mom.isValid()) {
     console.log(moment(date, 'D. MMM YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
 } else {
     console.log('invalid date')
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using moment with german locale?

Comment: its in node.js I have installed it using npm. it has the directory of locales, it has the german locale in it

Comment: Did you follow [this guide](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/loading-into-nodejs/)?

Comment: Update format
`moment.updateLocale('en', {
    longDateFormat : {
        LT: "h:mm A",
        LTS: "h:mm:ss A",
        L: "MM/DD/YYYY",
        l: "M/D/YYYY",
        LL: "MMMM Do YYYY",
        ll: "MMM D YYYY",
        LLL: "MMMM Do YYYY LT",
        lll: "MMM D YYYY LT",
        LLLL: "dddd, MMMM Do YYYY LT",
        llll: "ddd, MMM D YYYY LT"
    }
});`

Answer (score 2):

First according to the "de" [locale file](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/locale/de.js) in the momentJS repository on Github, the shortMonth for **März** is **Mrz.** (yes with a dot .) check code below (from the same file):

```
monthsShort : 'Jan._Febr._Mrz._Apr._Mai_Jun._Jul._Aug._Sept._Okt._Nov._Dez.'.split('_')
```

Second, for your date, you don't need to reparse it, just format your moment directly:

```
mom.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Putting everything together:

```
var date = "26. Mrz. 1995";
var mom = moment(date, "D. MMM YYYY", "de", true);

if (mom.isValid()) {
    console.log(mom.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
} else {
    console.log("invalid date");
}
```